# Bluetooth name is not displaying in my Lumia 525 Windows Phone?

Tags: settings, bluetooth, nokia-lumia-525

In my Lumia 525 Windows Phone I have problem with my Bluetooth. If I switch on my Bluetooth it's not showing the devices (Bluetooth on) name which are near to me. But sometimes it's showing and most of the times it won't. What is the reason for this bug? Does any Lumia 525 users facing the same issue? Am I wrongly using any settings option?

Comment: Can you see the devices with another phone? Make sure they are not set to hidden.

Comment: How soon after turning Bluetooth on, are you expecting to find the other devices?